# Why is the size of an array inconsisten depending on its location in the source code?

Tags: c++, gcc, sizeof

I can declare `animal_array1` and `animal_array2`. First one on the stack, while the second one is ... well, still on the stack but this time declared as a function parameter. Here is a sample code:

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 struct Animal
 {
 };

 void test(Animal animal_array2[10])
 {
     Animal animal_array1[10];
     if(sizeof(animal_array2) == sizeof(animal_array1))
         cout << "Both sizes are equal. That's expected!" << endl;
     else
         cout << "Mhhh sizes are *NOT* equal. That wasn't expected at all!" << endl;

 }

 int main()
 {
     Animal unused_var[10];
     test(unused_var);
 }
```

The output is:

```
 $./a.out 
 Mhhh sizes are *NOT* equal. That wasn't expected at all!
```

How can it be? Gcc bug? Or is it standard behavior? How can we get such streched results from the same apparent type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c

Comment: It's important to be aware that there are two distinct rules at play here. One is that a parameter declaration of array type is "adjusted" so that it's really of pointer type; `void func(int arr[10])` really means `void func(int *arr)`. (The fact that the `10` is silently ignored is one of the more annoying features of both C and C++.) The other is that an expression of array type is, in most but not all contexts, implicitly *converted* to a pointer to the array's first element. This latter rule is not specific to functions or function calls.

Comment: @KeithThompson, it's not ignored silently on clang: `warning: sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'Animal *' instead of 'Animal [10]' [-Wsizeof-array-argument]`. I wish gcc would warn about it too. I don't know if clang warns on all cases where the type difference makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are the only data types in C and C++ that cannot be passed by value. So an array decays to a pointer to the first element of the array (when declared and passed) as a function parameter.

So basically this:

```
void test(Animal animal_array2[10])
```

is actually:

```
void test(Animal *animal_array2)
```

but **only as  function parameter**

and the array passed as a parameter:

```
test(unused_var);
```

decays to a pointer to the first elem in the array:

```
test(&(unused_var[0]));
```

(*as a sidenote:* but without the actual dereferencing)

Answer (score 3):

Arrays will decay into pointers when passed to a function in C++. Typically what you do is pass the known size to the function, as a separate parameter. Not in the between the square brackets.